# How to declare variable in javascript code that is declared in another file?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

So I am using Laravel 5.5, PHP 7.0

I have this at the bottom of my views file:

```
$("#myRange").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    min: {{ $minPrice }},
    max: {{ $maxPrice}},
    @if(isset($returnData['Ranges']) && count($returnData['Ranges']) > 0)
        from: {{ $returnData['Ranges']['0'] }},
        to: {{ $returnData['Ranges']['1'] }}
    @else
        from: {{ $minPrice }},
        to: {{ $maxPrice}}
    @endif
});
```

The error is that $minPrice and $maxPrice are undeclared.  BUT they are declared in my controllers file.

Here's the code in my controller file:

```
    $fees = array_unique($fees);
    $priceRanges = array();
    $minPrice = 0;
    $maxPrice = 0;
    if(count($fees) > 0){
        foreach ($fees as $key => $value) {
            $range = explode(' - ', $value);
            $priceRanges[] = $range['0'];
            $priceRanges[] = $range['1'];
        }
        $priceRanges = array_unique($priceRanges);
        $minPrice = (int) min($priceRanges);
        $maxPrice = (int) max($priceRanges);
    }
```

Anybody how how can I fix the javascript code in my views (front-end) file to declare the variable?  I get this error on one specific page only which shows a list of items in my database.  If I search for an item from the homepage and then see the search results page, there's no error.  Only on the listings page.

Comment: Are you returning the view - listingpage with variables `$minPrice` and `$maxPrice` in your controller?

Comment: If a variable is declared in PHP is of no interest to JavaScript. If JS needs a variable, it must be declared in JS and not remotely in PHP.

Comment: @zuif No, those variables are used only for the searchresults filter function meaning when someone searches for something and then filters the results a bit more.

Comment: @Dormilich How would I declare it in JS?  I didn't actually make the code.  Another person did but he didn't want to spend time helping me with this so I'm going to assume that the variable needs to be both in the PHP and JS?

Comment: Well, you still have to provide the variable from your controller. That is, return the view with variable. `return view('listingpage', compact('minPrice, maxPrice'));` Given that, the JS code is on the view itself, under a <script> tag

Comment: @Dormilich you can still use the variable defined in the PHP controller, in your JS code, as long as the JS code is in the associated view.

Comment: so where do I put that return view code at?  After the @endif line?

Comment: @Thomas No you return the view from your controller. Can you post all of your controller file?

Comment: My controller is a loooong file.  I'll send you a message via chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166483/discussion-between-thomas-and-zuif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Javascript, do this

```
   $("#myRange").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",
    grid: true,
    min: @if(isset($minPrice)) {{ $minPrice }} @else 0 @endif,
    max: @if(isset($maxPrice)) {{ $maxPrice }} @else 0 @endif,
    @if(isset($returnData['Ranges']) && count($returnData['Ranges']) > 0)
        from: {{ $returnData['Ranges']['0'] }},
        to: {{ $returnData['Ranges']['1'] }}
    @else
        from: @if(isset($minPrice)) {{ $minPrice }} @else 0 @endif,
        to: @if(isset($maxPrice)) {{ $maxPrice }} @else 0 @endif
    @endif
});
```

If the value exists, echo it out, or else echo 0

Comment: Thanks for the chat.  This worked :)  I guess the @if(isset did the trick.

Comment: Now another problem.  On the search results page, the only thing that displays is the data representing maxPrice.  It's just a blank white page with the value at the top left corner.

Answer (score -3):

Declare it using good old spaghetti code:

```
<?php
$minPrice = 0;
$maxPrice = 0;
?>
```

They don't need to be exposed to JavaScript.

Comment: wait, now I'm confused.  I have that in my controller file.  I can remove it from my js code?  What would I do with the min: and max: ?